# iPhone - 3mb file into a NSArray == 22mb

Tags: iphone, memory-management

My app is shutting down on a 3G iPhone at ~23mb..

I'm loading a 3mb file into an NSArray as follows... Are str and lines not auto releasing? Any suggestions on a better way to do this?

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path 
              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSArray *lines = [str componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"];
[self parseDictLines:lines];


- (void)parseDictLines:(NSArray *)lines {
    int i = 0; 
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSMutableArray *word_list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *line in lines) {
        i++;
        [arr addObject:line];

        if ( i == 3 ) {
            i = 0;
            [word_list addObject:[arr copy]];
            [arr removeAllObjects];
        }
    }
    self.mDict = (NSArray*)word_list;
    [word_list release];
}
```

EDIT - The app is < 1mb before this code or if I skip this code. It is 22mb after it runs... So it can't be the temp variables.. Its usable until I do something that adds another 1mb at which point it bails.

EDIT2 - The NSString *str of the file is 5.9mb - I assume due to the way the string is encoded in memory is twice as big as the UTF8 file. The *lines array is also that size.

However str was not getting released immediately until I added the auto release pool. Running with instruments it takes 5 minutes for the NSArray *lines to fill up, after [lines release] is called it took about 3 minutes before the memory started going away and 5 minutes after that before the memory used by the *lines array was down to < 1mb. My mDict array is 14mb. I don't know why since its not that much different than NSArray *lines which was 6mb...

The below code solves my problem which obviously was that I was hitting the memory limit before the str and lines memory was released. Now that str gets released right away that frees up 6mb and its not possible for the user to go over the limit now while this code is loading in the background.

BUT - Why is the OS dumping my app when I've already auto released 12mb? Wouldn't it clean up anything that needs to be auto released on its own?

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSArray *lines = [[str componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"] retain];
[pool drain];
[self parseDictLines:lines];
[lines release];
```

Comment: Perhaps don't load the entire array at once: but rather load-on-demand (paged or individual entries or whatnot). It will take a little be more up-front design, and may not always be applicable. Perhaps it might be better stored in a binary-tree or heap or utilize another storage mechanism.

Comment: If the file is 3mb, I have to imagine whats basically an NSArray of the lines couldn't be that much more than 3mb...  I must be making a mistake in the above code. I can probably subset this then load the rest on demand from a file we'll see. I didn't want to get crazy since I'm new to ObjectiveC

Comment: run `instruments` on your app and see if you can identify memory leaks, it a wonderful tool

Comment: How many lines are in your file? Any unicode characters?

Comment: When you say that the app is <1mb before this code, what code are you talking about? I ask because I am wondering what you do with with the str and lines variables after you use them.

Comment: Yeah the file is half unicode characters. So as I noted above in EDIT2 its 6mb in memory not the 3mb file size... I think I've solved this, though I didn't realize I'd need 14mb to store my mDict array which is basically just this 3mb file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to set up an NSAutoRelease pool before the loop, that you drain right after `[arr removeAllObjects]`.  Draining a pool is the same as releasing it, so after that you have to alloc/init the pool again.

Comment: Since I'm at 22mb peak and it stays there after this code runs I'm not sure this solves anything, but I'll play around with this tomorrow. Could the str and lines be getting released but not freed up? Draining the pool releases autorelease vars? Or frees memory as well (garbage collects??)

Answer (score 3):

you're over-retaining the `arr` variable. You should replace

```
[word_list addObject:[arr copy]];
```

with

```
[word_list addObject:arr];
```

Comment: I'm doing an alloc of arr before the loop and reusing arr in the loop so I assume I have to [arr copy] otherwise word_list would end up with 10000 copies of the same empty array as I [arr removeAllObjects] last.

Comment: @Mark, you're right about that. You'd end up with 10,000 references to the same empty array (or an array of 1 or 2 lines if the number of lines is not an even multiple of 3)

Comment: @Mark: That may be so, but you are still leaking the copy of the array. Replace `[word_list addObject:[arr copy]];` with `[word_list addObject:[[arr copy] autorelease]];`

Comment: I just read over the memory management docs again thanks. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH

Answer (score 0):

Run it through Instrument's Allocations instrument and you should be able to see where the memory is going.